# How do I place a tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose i have a tikz picture, and in the latex code, I put it between a theorem and a definition, but when I compile, the picture shows up in the middle of the theorem's proof. I think its because the compiler doesn't want any blank space, so it puts the picture where its convenient. How do I specify where exactly to place the picture?

Comment: LaTeX considers everything between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}` (or in `\tikz ...code... ;`) as an *in line* element. If you want to make a `tikzpicture` a floating element you have to nest it in a `figure` environment. As for your specific question, it is not clear what the problem is and what you want to achieve. Maybe adding an example MWE (at least what you already tried and gave you problems) would help.

Comment: Assuming you use the `figure`-environment, there is no difference between a `tikzpicture` and a 'usual' one.

Comment: Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. As others have said already, it is the way that you are including the 'tikz' environment that it causing it to float so no one can really answer your question until they see your code.